# JasperReports: Printing a sentence in multiple lines

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to print a phrase in multiple lines for example :

> Here's the text="FOR TESTING PURPOSE ONLY. PLEASE DO NOT SHIP.23456789012345678901234567890123456789 STOP"

[image]

Have you an idea how to do it please.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text field's Markup property to HTML.

Then make use of the new line tag:

```
<br/>
```